# How to implement the authorization through token and roles, in WEB API C #, SOAP architecture, through the use of repositories with stored procedures?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I implement the authorization through token and roles, in WEB API C #, SOAP architecture, through the use of repositories with stored procedures and dependency injection?

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
    else
    {
        string autenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
        string decodeautenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(autenticationToken));
        string[] userNamePassworArray = decodeautenticationToken.Split(':');
        string username = userNamePassworArray[0];
        string password = userNamePassworArray[1];

        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();


        //validate user credentials and obtain user roles (return List Roles) 
        model.Roleslist = _serviceUsuario.ObtenerRoles(username, password);

        if (model.Roleslist !=null)
        {
            //this line takes a list of roles and divides them with a comma.
            string ListRoles = string.Join(",", model.Roleslist.Select(x => x.Roles));

            //bacic authentication
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username), null);
```

I tried it in the following way, but it does not work

```
            //ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await model.Roleslist.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            //ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await model.Roleslist.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            //it does not work
            var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, ListRoles);
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            //  HResult = 0x80004002 Message = You can not convert an object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to the type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity'.
            FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
            string userData = ticket.UserData;
            string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, roles);
        }
        else
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it in the following way, but it does not work

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
        //validate user credentials //valida las credenciales de usuario  
        //model.usuario = _serviceUsuario.Login(context.UserName, context.Password);//bool
        //validate user credentials and obtain user roles //validar las credenciales de usuario y obtener roles de usuario
        model.Roleslist = _serviceUsuario.ObtenerRoles(context.UserName, context.Password);//List

        //ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (model.Roleslist == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.");
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement the authentication with Token without Entity Framework that is with the validation based on a stored procedure and roles.
The code is the following:

```
public class CredentialsAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    // ...

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

        //validate user credentials and obtain user roles (return List Roles) 
        //validar las credenciales de usuario y obtener roles de usuario
        var user = model.User = _serviceUsuario.ObtenerUsuario(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.cod 01");
            return;
        }

        var stringRoles = user.Roles.Replace(" ", "");
        string[] roles = stringRoles.Split(',');
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        foreach (var Rol in roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Rol));
        }

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(context.UserName);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);

        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
}
```

Configure la aplicación para el flujo basado en OAuth

```
PublicClientId = "self";
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    //Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    Provider = new CredentialsAuthorizationServerProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    // En el modo de producción establezca AllowInsecureHttp = false
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};

// Permitir que la aplicación use tokens portadores para autenticar usuarios
//app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
```

Startup

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        var authOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(authOptions);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use your native language in the answer.